# Display encrypted file using QLPreviewController on iOS 14.2

Tags: ios, excel, encryption, ios14, qlpreviewcontroller

I have an encrypted excel file locally stored which I need to preview in my iPhone app.I use MicrosoftOffice App to decrypt and open, the display is normal. But I decrypt it with QLPreviewController and display "Decrypted failed". Moreover, the problem only occurs in some mobile phones with iOS14 or above, not all mobile phones. Does anyone have this problem? Is this an apple bug?

Comment: I found an iPhone 11, the system version is IOS 13.6, the test found that the decryption was successful, but when I upgraded it to IOS 14.2, the decryption failed! Any ideas?

Comment: If this worked before on previous iOS versions, I think it's worth filing a bug report via Apple's developer portal.

Comment: @Raffael At present, I just want to know if anyone else has the same problem. If the problem is common, I think I will give feedback to Apple.